# sound request:modern prison doors and buzzers

Tags: trade, field-recording

Hi all,

I'm currently working on a film that has a few prison scenes and my prison contact may not be able to get me in to a proper facility to record my own stuff in time, so I'm sending up a flare here.

I don't have a bunch of heavy intense needs.  Really just a modern prison buzzer or two and a few automated door opens and closes.  Also, any authentic prison yard weightlifting or mess hall ambiances would be useful, though we have loop group coming in to cover much of that.

I have a large personal library of sounds available to trade, so hit me up: rene [at] dallasaudipost.com and we'll see if we can get something worked out.

thanks!

Comment: @Rene, thanks for posting your request. I believe that users helping other users is one of the strongest aspects of this site.

Comment: I'd suggest finding a freight elevator...much easier to gain access to than a prison. I recently recorded one and the doors/buzzers sounded very close to a modern prison. Especially distant perspectives. I'd trade; but since I was doing it for work, the sounds aren't mine to give away...

Answer (score 1):

Hi Rene, i also edited the sound for a film with a lot of prison scenes too, but this was three years ago, so i have check my archives to see what i can get.
I'll try to send you news soon.

Cheers,

Pedro.

Answer (score 1):

At my day job, we have some loudly-popping card access doors that I can get you, if you think that'll help.  It won't be as awesome as real prison sounds, though.

Comment: while I'll take any help I can get, I need something that feels very authentic.  Do you participate here: http://thesoundcollectorsclub.wordpress.com/
the theme this month is door bells and buzzers, and your stuff could make a strong contribution there.  I'm going to upload my own stuff later on today I think.

Comment: I was thinking about it, this month. Do you have to be a member to donate sounds?

Comment: you do, but what you get back in sounds recorded by others makes it very very worth it. There are some excellent recordists that participate.  I certainly pay the fee and participate.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Rene, I uploaded "Electronic Door Lock" sounds (96/24) at Pond5 library 1 month ago.Listen :)
Hope that helps.

Comment: i could not find that very easily.  link?

Comment: https://www.pond5.com/video-sound-effects-music-after-effects-photos-illustrations/1/artist:Membrans.html

Answer (score 1):

In my University we've got monsterous automatic doors in the main building. They sound huge!

I'll try to make more or less fine recording, and post it here or mail you if I succeed .)))) (Main problem is that noisy students go here and there, hehe)

Comment: take a swing at it!  I'll trade you some cool stuff when you get it done.  thx!

Comment: @solipse, sounds like a guerrilla after-midnight recording session is in your future!

Comment: I've recorded some stuff already, but need to edit it.

Anyway, I think I've already missed Rene's deadline, so I'll just put all my Tokyo sounds in one archive, upload them and post them here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't laugh, because I don't know if I actually mean this serious :)

http://soundcloud.com/michaelmanzke/kaffeemaschine

Maybe that first angry buzz made by this coffeemachine can help you...or it's just one stupid idea =)

Comment: That's a gnarly little buzz! I don't know how authentic Rene's needs to go with, but I could totally see that working in a pinch. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

I used these buzzer sounds at my summer job.  (http://www.evl.uic.edu/caylor/MASTERS/AUDIO/buzzer.wav, http://waes-elearn.waes.ac.uk/moodle-resources/Childcare/pre-school/sounds%20effects/other%20sound%20effects/NATURE/buzzer.mp3).  I found a bunch more on findsound.com, freesound.org, and a bunch of other creative commons sites.  I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for but I hope that helps.